# get back to the previous location after 'cd' command?

Tags: unix, cd

I'm writing a shell script that needs to `cd` to some location. Is there any way to get back to the previous location, that is, the location before `cd` was executed?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can simply do

```
cd -
```

that will take you back to your previous location.

Some shells let you use pushdir/popdir commands, [check out this site](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/bash-shell-directory-shortcuts). You may also find this [SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/231881/push-pop-current-directory) useful.

Comment: Thanks. The `pushd` and `popd` would work! :) But is there a way to turn off the echo? (ie., let those commands execute 'quiety'?)

Comment: @OneTwoThree I don't know as I usually use `cd -`. However, you could alwayd do something like `pushd > /dev/null` as a work around. If you are putting this into a script, there may be an option to silence your shell.

Comment: this site http://www.linuxmisc.com/12-unix-shell/7d94a90c6614ef93.htm
suggests putting `pushd_silent=true` into `$HOME/.bashrc`, not sure if
that will work though.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running inside a script, you can also run part of the script inside a sub-process, which will have a private value of $PWD.

```
# do some work in the base directory, eg. echoing $PWD
echo $PWD

# Run some other command inside subshell
( cd ./new_directory; echo $PWD )

# You are back in the original directory here:
echo $PWD
```

This has its advantages and disadvantages... it does isolate the directory nicely, but spawning sub-processes may be expensive if you're doing it a lot. ( EDIT: as @Norman Gray points out below, the performance penalty of spawning the sub-process probably isn't very expensive relative to whatever else is happening in the rest of the script )

For the sake of maintainability, I typically use this approach unless I can prove that the script is running slowly because of it.

Comment: +1 in principle, but have you _measured_ a performance hit?  Since every command that isn't a shell built-in will do a fork, I doubt that the fork for a subshell is likely to incur any significant performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

You could echo PWD into a variable and the cd back to that variable. It may be quieter.

Comment: Isn't that `$OLDPWD`?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is a small set of functions that you can add to your .bashrc that allow you to go to named directories:

```
# cd /some/horribly/long/path
# save spud
# cd /some/other/horrible/path
# save green
...
# go spud
/some/horribly/long/path
```

This is documented at [A directory navigation productivity tool](http://www.krten.com/~rk/coding/gosave.html), but basically involves saving the output of "pwd" into the named mnemonics ("spud" and "green") in the above case, and then cd'ing to the contents of the files.